# looping through individual result of select operation in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures

i am trying to learn stored procedures in mysql, and this may not be the best scenario where you would need to use SP, but still its a learning process :)

I have a table, say `table1` with following columns:

```
table1_name, table1_location
```

I have another table, say `table2` with following columns

```
table2_name, table2_location
```

Assume that table1 has 5 records now, and that the table2 is blank. I would like to run an SP, and have all the table1_name and table1_location data to be entered into table2_name and table2_location respectively.

This is the mysql code i have written -

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE INS()
BEGIN
SELECT table1_name, table1_location FROM table1;
SET name, location VARCHAR(50);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (name, location);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

THis code obviously doesnt work! My concern is, since there are 5 records already, then table1_name would be sort of an array with 5 values, and table1_location would also be an array with 5 values, as would normally be returned by a SELECT operation. How do i get each cell value and then do an insert operation?

I m quite new to mysql/SP..bear with me :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for your learning, the answer has nothing to do with stored procedures.

The insert can take the results of the select:

```
INSERT into table2
SELECT name, location
FROM table1
```

If you get to something where you really need to loop across a rowset in a stored procedure, check out [cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html).

Comment: like i said, i am trying to learn SP through practice, and that was not the best example, i know. I think like you suggested Cursor could be what i am looking for. May I know, if a select query inside an SP returns multiple rows with multiple columns, then is cursor the only way of iterating through each row's columns?

Comment: They may be some other voodoo way of doing it, but cursors are the right way.  Good luck!